# ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a special type of neural network with Keras functional API, as seen below:

[image]

But I'm having a problem with the concatenate layer:

> ValueError: A "Concatenate" layer requires inputs with matching shapes
>   except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 160, 160, 384),
>   (None, 160, 160, 48)]

**Notice**: From my research I assume that this question is not duplicate, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183229/valueerror-concatenate-layer-requires-inputs-with-matching-shapes-except-for), and [this post](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/29673286) (translated with Google), but they don't seem to work (instead, they make problems even slightly "worse").

---

Here's the code of the neural network before concat layer:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, concatenate
from keras.activations import relu
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform, Constant, TruncatedNormal

#  Network 1, Layer 1
screenshot = Input(shape=(1280, 1280, 0), dtype='float32', name='screenshot')
# padded1 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=5, data_format=None)(screenshot)
conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=11, strides=(4, 4), activation=relu, padding='same')(screenshot)
# conv1 = Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=11, strides=(4, 4), activation=relu, padding='same')(padded1)
pooling1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv1)
normalized1 = BatchNormalization()(pooling1)  # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145768/importance-of-local-response-normalization-in-cnn

# Network 1, Layer 2

# padded2 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=2, data_format=None)(normalized1)
conv2 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, activation=relu, padding='same')(normalized1)
# conv2 = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=5, activation=relu, padding='same')(padded2)
normalized2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
# padded3 = ZeroPadding2D(padding=1, data_format=None)(normalized2)
conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=3, activation=relu, padding='same',
               kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01),
               bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(normalized2)
# conv3 = Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=3, activation=relu, padding='same',
#               kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(stddev=0.1),
#               bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(padded3)

# Network 2, Layer 1

textmaps = Input(shape=(160, 160, 128), dtype='float32', name='textmaps')
txt_conv1 = Conv2D(filters=48, kernel_size=1, activation=relu, padding='same',
                   kernel_initializer=TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.01), bias_initializer=Constant(value=0.1))(textmaps)

# (Network 1 + Network 2), Layer 1

merged = concatenate([conv3, txt_conv1], axis=1)
```

This is how interpreter evaluates variables `conv3` and `txt_conv1`:

```
>>> conv3
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_3/Relu:0' shape=(?, 160, 160, 384) dtype=float32>
>>> txt_conv1
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_4/Relu:0' shape=(?, 160, 160, 48) dtype=float32>
```

This is how the interpreter evaluates `txt_conv1` and `conv3` variables after setting `image_data_format` to `channels_first`:

```
>>> conv3
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_3/Relu:0' shape=(?, 384, 160, 0) dtype=float32>
>>> txt_conv1
<tf.Tensor 'conv2d_4/Relu:0' shape=(?, 48, 160, 128) dtype=float32>
```

Both of the layers have shapes which are not actually described in the architecture.

---

Is there any way to solve this problem? Maybe I didn't write the appropriate code (I'm new to Keras).

P.S

I know that the code above is not organized, I'm just testing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the axis to -1 in the concatenate layer since the shapes of the two tensors that you want to concatenate only differ in their last dimension. The resulting tensor will then be of shape `(?, 160, 160, 384 + 48)`.

Comment: Well that was a quick fix, what's strange is that Caffe based neural network definitions use `axis=1` for concatenation layer, which is the reason for why I picked it. But regardless, dimension of the new shape is 432 as described in the architecture. Thank you!